# Rounding time in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time, modulo, rounding

What would be an elegant, efficient and Pythonic way to perform a h/m/s rounding operation on time related types in Python with control over the rounding resolution?

My guess is that it would require a time modulo operation. Illustrative examples:

- 20:11:13 % (10 seconds) => (3 seconds)
- 20:11:13 % (10 minutes) => (1 minutes and 13 seconds)

Relevant time related types I can think of:

- `datetime.datetime` \ `datetime.time`
- `struct_time`

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463930/how-to-round-the-minute-of-a-datetime-object-python

Comment: Do you want to round a date to the nearest 'part' (i.e. 20:11:10 rounded to nearest hour yields 20:00:00) or - as your example suggests - get the _remainder_ after rounding to the nearest part (i.e. 20:11:10 to nearest hour yields 11:13)?

Comment: Sorry; For 'date' read 'time'

Comment: related: [Rounding up to nearest 30 minutes in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32723150/4279)

Answer (score 18):

For a datetime.datetime rounding, see this function:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10854034/1431079

Sample of use:

```
print roundTime(datetime.datetime(2012,12,31,23,44,59,1234),roundTo=60*60)
2013-01-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 16):

How about use `datetime.timedelta`s:

```
import time
import datetime as dt

hms=dt.timedelta(hours=20,minutes=11,seconds=13)

resolution=dt.timedelta(seconds=10)
print(dt.timedelta(seconds=hms.seconds%resolution.seconds))
# 0:00:03

resolution=dt.timedelta(minutes=10)
print(dt.timedelta(seconds=hms.seconds%resolution.seconds))
# 0:01:13
```

Comment: That would work with `datetime.time` but not with `datetime.datetime` as you didn't take into account the date

Answer (score 5):

This will round up time data to a resolution as asked in the question:

```py
import datetime as dt

current = dt.datetime.now()
current_td = dt.timedelta(
    hours = current.hour, 
    minutes = current.minute, 
    seconds = current.second, 
    microseconds = current.microsecond)

# to seconds resolution
to_sec = dt.timedelta(seconds = round(current_td.total_seconds()))
print(dt.datetime.combine(current, dt.time(0)) + to_sec)

# to minute resolution
to_min = dt.timedelta(minutes = round(current_td.total_seconds() / 60))
print(dt.datetime.combine(current, dt.time(0)) + to_min)

# to hour resolution
to_hour = dt.timedelta(hours = round(current_td.total_seconds() / 3600))
print(dt.datetime.combine(current, dt.time(0)) + to_hour)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert both times to seconds, do the modulo operati

```
from datetime import time

def time2seconds(t):
    return t.hour*60*60+t.minute*60+t.second

def seconds2time(t):
    n, seconds = divmod(t, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(n, 60)
    return time(hours, minutes, seconds)

def timemod(a, k):
    a = time2seconds(a)
    k = time2seconds(k)
    res = a % k
    return seconds2time(res)

print(timemod(time(20, 11, 13), time(0,0,10)))
print(timemod(time(20, 11, 13), time(0,10,0)))
```

Outputs:

```
00:00:03
00:01:13
```

Answer (score 3):

I use following code snippet to round to the next hour:

```
import datetime as dt

tNow  = dt.datetime.now()
# round to the next full hour
tNow -= dt.timedelta(minutes = tNow.minute, seconds = tNow.second, microseconds =  tNow.microsecond)
tNow += dt.timedelta(hours = 1)
```

Comment: that doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: It's actually the only answer that directly answers the question title, which is about *rounding* (and happens to be what I'm looking for). The question body contradicts the title. This is just a bad question. Thanks, PTH.

Comment: Careful: if `tNow` is already rounded to the nearest hour, then this will increment by an hour instead of doing nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd convert the time in seconds, and use standard modulo operation from that point.

20:11:13 = `20*3600 + 11*60 + 13` = 72673 seconds

`72673 % 10 = 3`

`72673 % (10*60) = 73`

This is the easiest solution I can think about.

Comment: If you wanted to bother with special cases, modulo n seconds, where n is in (2,3,4,5,10,12,15,20,30), can be done with just the seconds part.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lossy* version of hourly rounding:

```
dt = datetime.datetime
now = dt.utcnow()
rounded = dt.utcfromtimestamp(round(now.timestamp() / 3600, 0) * 3600)
```

Same principle can be applied to different time spans.

**The above method assumes UTC is used, as any timezone information will be destroyed in conversion to timestamp.*

Answer (score -1):

You could also try [pandas.Timestamp.round](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.round.html):

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

t = datetime.datetime(2012,12,31,23,44,59,1234)
print(pd.to_datetime(t).round('1min'))
% Timestamp('2012-12-31 23:45:00')
```

You can perform the following if you want to change the result back to datetime format:

```
pd.to_datetime(t).round('1min').to_pydatetime()
% datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 31, 23, 45)
```