# How to round a timezone-aware date in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I am trying to convert default timezone `datetime` to `localtime` and round the time to 15min slots in Django views. I have the following roundTime function:

```
def roundTime(dt=None, dateDelta=timedelta(minutes=1)):
    """Round a datetime object to a multiple of a timedelta
    dt : datetime.datetime object, default now.
    dateDelta : timedelta object, we round to a multiple of this, default 1 minute.
    Author: Thierry Husson 2012 - Use it as you want but don't blame me.
            Stijn Nevens 2014 - Changed to use only datetime objects as variables
    """
    roundTo = dateDelta.total_seconds()

    if dt == None:
        dt = datetime.now()
    seconds = (dt - dt.min).seconds
    # // is a floor division, not a comment on following line:
    rounding = (seconds+roundTo/2) // roundTo * roundTo
    return dt + timedelta(0,rounding-seconds,-dt.microsecond)
```

And here is what I have tried so far:

```
mytime = roundTime(datetime.now(),timedelta(minutes=15)).strftime('%H:%M:%S') #works OK
mytime = datetime.strptime(str(mytime), '%H:%M:%S') #works OK
mytime = timezone.localtime(mytime)
```

But the last line gives me this error:

> error: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime

And when I use:

```
local_time = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
```

I do get the correct local time, but for some reason I'm unable to round the time by doing:

```
mytime = roundTime(local_time,timedelta(minutes=15)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

which works with the `datetime.now()` above.

I was able to come up with this not pretty but working code:

```
mytime = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
mytime = datetime.strftime(mytime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
mytime = datetime.strptime(str(mytime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
mytime = roundTime(mytime,timedelta(minutes=15)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
mytime = datetime.strptime(str(mytime), '%H:%M:%S')
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Is `roundTime` a function of yours? If yes, can you show its code?

Comment: I have posted the `roundTime` and a working code that I came up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `roundTime` function that you are using does not work with timezone-aware dates.
To support it, you could modify it like this:

```
def roundTime(dt=None, dateDelta=timedelta(minutes=1)):
    """Round a datetime object to a multiple of a timedelta
    dt : datetime.datetime object, default now.
    dateDelta : timedelta object, we round to a multiple of this, default 1 minute.
    Author: Thierry Husson 2012 - Use it as you want but don't blame me.
            Stijn Nevens 2014 - Changed to use only datetime objects as variables
    """
    roundTo = dateDelta.total_seconds()

    if dt == None : 
        dt = datetime.now()
    #Make sure dt and datetime.min have the same timezone
    tzmin = dt.min.replace(tzinfo=dt.tzinfo)

    seconds = (dt - tzmin).seconds
    # // is a floor division, not a comment on following line:
    rounding = (seconds+roundTo/2) // roundTo * roundTo
    return dt + timedelta(0,rounding-seconds,-dt.microsecond)
```

That way the function works with both naive and TZ-aware dates.
Then you can proceed as in your second attempt:

```
local_time = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) 
mytime = roundTime(local_time, timedelta(minutes=15))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did not want to mess with he `roundTime` function as is is being used elsewhere as well. Perhaps I can do another version for the time zone needs. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: This new version will behave as before in the rest of your code, it just supports a new use case that you were not using before (you can be sure that you were not using it as you would have got an error)

Comment: @WayBehind: the rounding may cross a DST  boundary and therefore [the attached tzinfo should be updated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33015258/4279).

Answer (score 2):

To round a timezone-aware datetime object, [make it a naive datetime object, round it, and attach the correct time zone info for the rounded time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32724959/4279):

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone

def round_time(dt=None, delta=timedelta(minutes=1)):
    if dt is None:
        dt = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) # assume USE_TZ=True
    tzinfo, is_dst = dt.tzinfo, bool(dt.dst())
    dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=None)
    f = delta.total_seconds()
    rounded_ordinal_seconds = f * round((dt - dt.min).total_seconds() / f)
    rounded_dt = dt.min + timedelta(seconds=rounded_ordinal_seconds)
    localize = getattr(tzinfo, 'localize', None)
    if localize:
        rounded_dt = localize(rounded_dt, is_dst=is_dst)
    else:
        rounded_dt = rounded_dt.replace(tzinfo=tzinfo)
    return rounded_dt
```

To avoid floating point issues, all computations could be rewritten using integer microseconds (`dt.resolution`).

Example:

```
>>> round_time(delta=timedelta(minutes=15))
```