# How to round a datetime up to a specific time?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

Given a datetime object, how do I round it up to the next occurrence of 8AM PST?

Comment: Make a new datetime, use input from the current datetime year, month, day and set hours, mins, seconds as 8, 0, 0 respectively

Comment: @Ian: This would always be today's 8AM. To always round up, you need to add another day on top unless it is before 8AM.

Comment: related: [Rounding up to nearest 30 minutes in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32723150/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the result is a timezone-aware datetime object in a timezone with a non-fixed UTC offset then you can't just call `.replace()` or `.combine()` -- it may create a datetime with a wrong UTC offset. The issue is similar to [How do I get the UTC time of "midnight" for a given timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373370/4279) (`00:00` is used instead of `08:00`).

Assuming 8AM always exists and unambiguous in PST:

```
from datetime import datetime, time as datetime_time, timedelta
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

def next_8am_in_pst(aware_dt, tz=pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')):
    pst_aware_dt = tz.normalize(aware_dt.astimezone(tz)) # convert to PST
    naive_dt = round_up_to_8am(pst_aware_dt.replace(tzinfo=None))
    return tz.localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None)

def round_up_to_8am(dt):
    rounded = datetime.combine(dt, datetime_time(8))
    return rounded + timedelta(rounded < dt)
```

Example:

```
>>> str(next_8am_in_pst(datetime.now(pytz.utc))) 
'2016-02-25 08:00:00-08:00'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works across daylight saving boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

Just test whether the time is before or after 8, then add a day if it's after and construct a new datetime.

```
import datetime

def round_datetime(dt):
    t = datetime.time(8)
    # If time is after 8am, add a day.
    if dt.time() > datetime.time(8):
        dt += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return datetime.datetime.combine(dt, t)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize you could split up the date and time like that.

Comment: if the input is a timezone-aware datetime object then it is more complex (your code is ok if the input is  a naive datetime object).

Answer (score 0):

I made an answer based on some ideas from the comments:

```
def nextDay(d):
    pstTime = d.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
    pstTime = pstTime.replace(hour=8, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

    if pstTime < d:
        pstTime += datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    return pstTime
```

Comment: it may fail around dates with a DST transition