# Convert datetime to the cloest time point

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a dateset as below.

```
                      dummy                
datetime
2015-10-25 06:00:00      1 
2015-04-05 20:00:00      1 
2015-11-24 00:00:00      1 
2015-08-18 08:00:00      1 
2015-10-21 12:00:00      1
```

I want to change the datetime to the cloest predefined time point, say 00:00:00 and 12:00:00

```
                      dummy                
datetime
2015-10-25 00:00:00      1 
2015-04-05 12:00:00      1 
2015-11-24 00:00:00      1 
2015-08-18 00:00:00      1 
2015-10-21 12:00:00      1
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/32723150/4636715 for rounding up to closest top/bottom of hour.

Comment: Use `df.index.floor('12H')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible use [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html):

```
df.index = df.index.floor('12H')
print (df)
                     dummy
datetime                  
2015-10-25 00:00:00      1
2015-04-05 12:00:00      1
2015-11-24 00:00:00      1
2015-08-18 00:00:00      1
2015-10-21 12:00:00      1
```