# bash round minutes to 5

Tags: bash, timestamp

We have this string to retrieve date and time in clean format.

```
 TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

Is there some inline code that we can use to round the minute to 5 down.
So if it is 12:03 it will make it 12:00 and if it is 12:49 it will be 12:45

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you mean `TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do this you can subtract the minutes modulo 5 from the total minutes. To print it out:

```
echo "$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M") - ($(date +%M)%5)" | bc
```

To save it to a variable:

```
my_var=$(echo "$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M") - ($(date +%M)%5)" | bc)
```

This relies on your date format string remaining as it is now - a string of numbers.

Example output:

```
$ date "+%Y%m%d%H%M"
201404010701
$ echo "$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M") - ($(date +%M)%5)" | bc
201404010700
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. But now the second thing. How to get this time in UTC (the machine is UTC + 2 timezone)

Comment: `echo "$(TZ=UTC date "+%Y%m%d%H%M") - ($(date +%M)%5)" | bc`

Comment: Is there some way to do the same in python ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463930/how-to-round-the-minute-of-a-datetime-object-python

Comment: I don't like the race condition

Answer (score 5):

You can use the integer division and multiply back to get the round value.

```
$ m=23
$ (( m /= 5, m *= 5 )) && echo $m
20
```

Integer division just return the integer part of the result, so in the case above is returning 4. Then multiplying by 5 gives 20.

In your case:

```
$ TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
$ echo $TIMESTAMP
201404011231
$ (( TIMESTAMP /= 5, TIMESTAMP *= 5 ))
$ echo $TIMESTAMP
201404011230

$ TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
$ echo $TIMESTAMP
201404011257
$ (( TIMESTAMP /= 5, TIMESTAMP *= 5 ))
$ echo $TIMESTAMP
201404011255
```

Comment: +1, I prefer Glenn's solution but this is also brief, easy to read and *fairly* portable. Note you can have multiple expressions in a single `(( ... ))` expression, e.g. `(( TIMESTAMP /= 5, TIMESTAMP *= 5 ))`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint, @AdrianFrühwirth , didn't know it :)

Answer (score 5):

A little string manipulation:

```
case $TIMESTAMP in 
    *[1234]) TIMESTAMP=${TIMESTAMP%?}0;; 
    *[6789]) TIMESTAMP=${TIMESTAMP%?}5;; 
esac
```

`${TIMESTAMP%?}` removes the last character. Ref: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: I like this the most since it's portable and invokes `date` only once.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly bash only but using [dateutils' dround](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/#dround) utility, it boils down to:

```
$ dround now -5m
2014-04-01T10:35:00
```

or with your format specifiers:

```
$ dround now -5m -f '%Y%m%d%H%M'
201404011035
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of that project.

Answer (score 2):

using the remainder operator the we can determine the number of excess minutes, that can then be subtracted from the original:

```
TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
(( TIMESTAMP -= TIMESTAMP%15 ))
echo $TIMESTAMP
```

this only works because both 100 and 60 are divisible by 5
if 15 minutes was wanted instead of 5 the expression would be more complex:

```
(( TIMESTAMP -= TIMESTAMP%100%5 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution of Fedorqui is very smart and versatile:

```
seconds=$(date +%s) 
echo $seconds $(date --date="@$seconds" +%H:%M:%S) # say 1559449650 # 06:27:30
# (( seconds /= 3600, seconds *= 3600 )) # rounds to this hour
# (( seconds += 3600, seconds /= 3600, seconds *= 3600 )) # rounds to next hour
(( seconds += 1800, seconds /= 1800, seconds *= 1800 )) # rounds to next half of a hour
next_hour=$(date --date="@$seconds" +%H:%M:%S)
echo $seconds $next_hour # say 1559449800 06:30:00
```

Answer (score 1):

With Bash:
Following one-liner rounds the minutes down to steps of 5 minutes:

```sh
d=$(date +'%M'); 
echo $(date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:')$((($(($d / 5))-0)*5))':'$(date +'%M')
```

```
output example:

Sat Apr 24 12:16:00 CEST 2021      
24/04/2021 12:15:16
```

Comment: one linters are impressive and useful in the terminal, but as an answer to a question, formatted/commented code is more valuable

Comment: Or just: `echo $(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:')$(( ($(date +'%M') / 5)*5 ))`

Answer (score 0):

With bash:

> TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M")

```
MINROUND=$((10#${TIMESTAMP:10:2} / 5 * 5))
if [ "${#MINROUND}" = 1 ]; then
  MINROUND="0$MINROUND"
fi
TIMESTAMP="${TIMESTAMP:0:10}${MINROUND}"
```