# Shell script to round off time to nearest 5 minutes

Tags: shell

```
date=$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M)
echo "CURRENT DATE-->" "$date"
```

How to round it off to the nearest five minutes? For example, the output should be:

```
2016_01_20_17_20
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash round minutes to 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22783007/608639)

Answer (score 4):

```
date -d @$(( (($(date +%s) + 150) / 300) * 300)) "+%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M"
```

The inner date call returns the epoch time in seconds, and then rounds (up or down) to nearest multiple of 300 (5 minutes). The outer date call formats as desired.