# Convert HH:MM:SS AM/PM string to time

Tags: r, time

I need to parse times in a character format like "1:36:22 PM".

I've tried various permutations of `as.POSIXct` and `strptime` but just can't get there. For example, this fails to pick up the importance of PM:

```
t <- "1:36:22 PM"
as.POSIXct(t, format = "%H:%M:%S")
# [1] "2016-09-08 01:36:22 BST"
```

and this fails:

```
strptime(t, "%H:%M:%S")
# [1] NA
```

Curiously, for reasons I can't understand, dropping the seconds from the input *may* work:

```
t <- "1:30:00 PM"
strptime(t, "%I:%M %p")
# [1] NA
 
t <- "1:30 PM"
strptime(t, "%I:%M %p")
# [1] "2016-09-08 13:30:00 BST"
```

All I want is for this to work:

```
t <- "1:30:00 PM"
SOME COMMAND HERE HERE
# [1] "13:30:00"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `format(strptime(t, "%I:%M:%S %p"), "%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: `hms::as.hms(lubridate::parse_date_time("1:30:00 PM", "IMS p"))`

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried using the lubridate package? It can handle AM/PM using the **%p indicator** in the "parse_date_time" function.

```
library(lubridate)
t <- "1:36:22 PM"
parse_date_time(t, '%I:%M:%S %p')
[1] "2016-09-08 13:36:22 UTC"
```

From the [lubridate documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf):

**%I:** *Hours as decimal number (01–12 or 1–12).*

**%M:** *Minute as decimal number (00–59 or 0–59).*

**%S:** *Second as decimal number (00–61 or 0–61).*

**%P:** *AM/PM indicator in the locale. Used in conjunction with I and not with H. An empty string in some locales.*

Comment: These abbreviations are part of base R.  See the documentation for `strptime` to see all the date-time abbreviations available.

Comment: In `parse_date_time` you don't need the `%` symbols; [it ignores them anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1157/date-and-time/7018/parsing-dates-and-datetimes-from-strings-with-lubridate#t=201609082306537640757).

Comment: using the command `ymd_hms` from `lubridate`, you don't even need to specify the formatting as long as you enter a reasonable date time value. It automatically converts from AM/PM to 24hr time.

Answer (score 11):

Use the conversion specifications `%I` and `%p`. See **Details** section in `?strptime`:

> `%I` Hours as decimal number (01–12).>

> `%p` AM/PM indicator in the locale. Used in conjunction with `%I` and **not** with `%H`.

```
strptime(t, "%I:%M:%S %p")
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Comment: ... also, it looks like you have `%l` (lower-case L) rather than `%I` (upper-case I) in your answer