# Error in rounding off datetime.time to nearest 60 minute mark

Tags: python, datetime

I have this `python` code where I am getting `current time`. Now I want to round it off to nearest `60` minute mark so that if `8:20` then it round off to `8:00` but if its `8:31` then it should round off to `9:00`. Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463930/how-to-round-the-minute-of-a-datetime-object-python/10854034#10854034) i tried this but it gives me error:

```
def roundTime(dt=None, roundTo=60):
   """Round a datetime object to any time laps in seconds
   dt : datetime.datetime object, default now.
   roundTo : Closest number of seconds to round to, default 1 minute.
   Author: Thierry Husson 2012 - Use it as you want but don't blame me.
   """
   if dt == None : dt = datetime.datetime.now()
   seconds = (dt.replace(tzinfo=None) - dt.min).seconds
   rounding = (seconds+roundTo/2) // roundTo * roundTo
   return dt + datetime.timedelta(0,rounding-seconds,-dt.microsecond)

def round_time():
    td = datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now())
    print(roundTime(td, roundTo=60 * 60))
```

The error I get is `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'`. How can resolve this error and round of the time? Also if there's a more easier way to achieve this please let me know?

**Additional related question:** Once I have the time rounded off I also want to find the time which is 3 hours after from the rounded off time. Does `+` operation works here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out `datetime.datetime.time` in `round_time()` function and it works:

```
def round_time():
    td = datetime.datetime.now()
    res = roundTime(td, roundTo=60 * 60).time()
    print(res)
```

If you want 3 more hours you can use `timedelta`:

```
def round_time():
    td = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=3) // plus 3 more hours
    res = roundTime(td, roundTo=60 * 60).time()
    print(res)
```

By the way, in `roundTime(dt=None, roundTo=60)` you should change to below code so you will get correct answer for current hour when you don't send in `dt`:

```
def roudTime(dt=None, roundTo = 60*60):
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in the function comment: the `dt` variable must be a `datetime.datetime` object (not a `datetime.time` object).

```
def round_time():
    dt = datetime.datetime.now()
    dt_rounded = roundTime(dt, roundTo=60 * 60)
    time_rounded = dt_rounded.time()
    print(time_rounded)
```