# Rounding time off to the nearest second - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime

I have a large dataset with more than 500 000 date & time stamps that look like this:

```
date        time
2017-06-25 00:31:53.993
2017-06-25 00:32:31.224
2017-06-25 00:33:11.223
2017-06-25 00:33:53.876
2017-06-25 00:34:31.219
2017-06-25 00:35:12.634
```

How do I round these timestamps off to the nearest second?

My code looks like this:

```
readcsv = pd.read_csv(filename)
log_date = readcsv.date
log_time = readcsv.time

readcsv['date'] = pd.to_datetime(readcsv['date']).dt.date
readcsv['time'] = pd.to_datetime(readcsv['time']).dt.time
timestamp = [datetime.datetime.combine(log_date[i],log_time[i]) for i in range(len(log_date))]
```

So now I have combined the dates and times into a list of `datetime.datetime` objects that looks like this:

```
datetime.datetime(2017,6,25,00,31,53,993000)
datetime.datetime(2017,6,25,00,32,31,224000)
datetime.datetime(2017,6,25,00,33,11,223000)
datetime.datetime(2017,6,25,00,33,53,876000)
datetime.datetime(2017,6,25,00,34,31,219000)
datetime.datetime(2017,6,25,00,35,12,634000)
```

Where do I go from here?
The `df.timestamp.dt.round('1s')` function doesn't seem to be working?
Also when using `.split()` I was having issues when the seconds and minutes exceeded 59

Many thanks

Comment: Please post the desired output for a time stamp.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463930/how-to-round-the-minute-of-a-datetime-object-python/10854034#10854034 use 1*60 as a parameter.

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: What is your dataset made of? A pandas dataframe, a CSV file? Is there anything you have tried to solve the problem?

Comment: http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Does something like this help? `round(float('2017-06-25 00:31:53.993'.split()[1].split(':')[-1]))`

Comment: The data is in a CSV file and  Iv used pandas to get the timestamps into this format. @srig That seems to be working thank you.

Comment: @Jetman If you're using pandas, there are much better solutions. Please take a look at my answer, and accept it if it helps you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `for loop` and `str.split()`:

```
dts = ['2017-06-25 00:31:53.993',
       '2017-06-25 00:32:31.224',
       '2017-06-25 00:33:11.223',
       '2017-06-25 00:33:53.876',
       '2017-06-25 00:34:31.219',
       '2017-06-25 00:35:12.634']

for item in dts:
    date = item.split()[0]
    h, m, s = [item.split()[1].split(':')[0],
               item.split()[1].split(':')[1],
               str(round(float(item.split()[1].split(':')[-1])))]

    print(date + ' ' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s)

2017-06-25 00:31:54
2017-06-25 00:32:31
2017-06-25 00:33:11
2017-06-25 00:33:54
2017-06-25 00:34:31
2017-06-25 00:35:13
>>>
```

You could turn that into a function:

```
def round_seconds(dts):
    result = []
    for item in dts:
        date = item.split()[0]
        h, m, s = [item.split()[1].split(':')[0],
                   item.split()[1].split(':')[1],
                   str(round(float(item.split()[1].split(':')[-1])))]
        result.append(date + ' ' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s)

    return result
```

Testing the function:

```
dts = ['2017-06-25 00:31:53.993',
       '2017-06-25 00:32:31.224',
       '2017-06-25 00:33:11.223',
       '2017-06-25 00:33:53.876',
       '2017-06-25 00:34:31.219',
       '2017-06-25 00:35:12.634']

from pprint import pprint

pprint(round_seconds(dts))

['2017-06-25 00:31:54',
 '2017-06-25 00:32:31',
 '2017-06-25 00:33:11',
 '2017-06-25 00:33:54',
 '2017-06-25 00:34:31',
 '2017-06-25 00:35:13']
>>>
```

Since you seem to be using Python 2.7, to drop any trailing zeros, you may need to change:

`str(round(float(item.split()[1].split(':')[-1])))`

to

`str(round(float(item.split()[1].split(':')[-1]))).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')`

I've just tried the function with Python 2.7 at [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/AnnualAlarmingIbadanmalimbe) and it ran as expected.

Comment: I believe this would fail for the edge case `'2017-06-25 00:31:59.993'`.

Comment: This only works when rounding down. Rounding up seconds doesn't update the minutes.

Answer (score 31):

Without any extra packages, a datetime object can be rounded to the nearest second with the following simple function:

```
import datetime as dt

def round_seconds(obj: dt.datetime) -> dt.datetime:
    if obj.microsecond >= 500_000:
        obj += dt.timedelta(seconds=1)
    return obj.replace(microsecond=0)
```

Comment: Small improvement here: To satisfy python's naming conventions, rename `roundSeconds` to `round_seconds` and all other camelCase names accordingly. Other than that, great answer!

Comment: This function leaves small amount of microseconds due to float precision. Answer by @Maciejo95 works without this problem.

Comment: Careful: This function is mutating the given object.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken How is this mutating the given object? In a quick test I don't see `.second` or `.microsecond` modified on the given object.

Comment: @qewg in what situations would you experience some microseconds left over? I've seen `microseconds` correctly set to `0` in all my cases.

Comment: @electrovir I was wrong. The function is indeed not mutating the object. The way the function is written tripped me a bit, because `new_date_time = date_time_object` does not create a copy. You can do all operations on the given object and it will still work. That is because datetime objects are immutable.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken gotcha, that makes sense. Feel free to edit the answer to make it read better! Python (along with all its conventions) isn't my one of my strongest languages.

Comment: I do not like not commented magic numbers in the code. Not going to give a try to this solution.

Answer (score 18):

The question doesn't say *how* you want to round. Rounding down would often be appropriate for a time function. This is not statistics.

```
rounded_down_datetime = raw_datetime.replace(microsecond=0)
```

Comment: Rounding to seconds means normally for >=0.5 you round to 1 for <0.5 you round to 0. Your answer is valid for cutting decimal part. It is not rounding.

Answer (score 16):

If anyone wants to round a single datetime item off to the nearest second, this one works just fine:

```
pandas.to_datetime(your_datetime_item).round('1s')
```

Comment: Also works with pandas column data.   I feel this is the best answer.

Comment: this solution changes output type (datetime.datetime -> pd.Timestamp), what not always is desirabled

Answer (score 9):

If you're using pandas, you can just `round` the data to the nearest second using `dt.round` -

```
df

                timestamp
0 2017-06-25 00:31:53.993
1 2017-06-25 00:32:31.224
2 2017-06-25 00:33:11.223
3 2017-06-25 00:33:53.876
4 2017-06-25 00:34:31.219
5 2017-06-25 00:35:12.634

df.timestamp.dt.round('1s')

0   2017-06-25 00:31:54
1   2017-06-25 00:32:31
2   2017-06-25 00:33:11
3   2017-06-25 00:33:54
4   2017-06-25 00:34:31
5   2017-06-25 00:35:13
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If `timestamp` isn't a `datetime` column, convert it first, using `pd.to_datetime` -

```
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
```

Then, `dt.round` should work.

Comment: Thanks very much, I can't believe I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 5):

Alternate version of @electrovir 's solution:

```
import datetime

def roundSeconds(dateTimeObject):
    newDateTime = dateTimeObject + datetime.timedelta(seconds=.5)
    return newDateTime.replace(microsecond=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing dataset into a file you can do like this:

```
with open('../dataset.txt') as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    cnt = 1
    while line:
        line = fp.readline()
        print "\n" + line.strip()
        sec = line[line.rfind(':') + 1:len(line)]
        rounded_num = int(round(float(sec)))
        print line[0:line.rfind(':') + 1] + str(rounded_num)
        print abs(float(sec) - rounded_num)
        cnt += 1
```

If you are storing dataset in a list:

```
dts = ['2017-06-25 00:31:53.993',
   '2017-06-25 00:32:31.224',
   '2017-06-25 00:33:11.223',
   '2017-06-25 00:33:53.876',
   '2017-06-25 00:34:31.219',
   '2017-06-25 00:35:12.634']

for i in dts:
    line = i
    print "\n" + line.strip()
    sec = line[line.rfind(':') + 1:len(line)]
    rounded_num = int(round(float(sec)))
    print line[0:line.rfind(':') + 1] + str(rounded_num)
    print abs(float(sec) - rounded_num)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this that:

- doesn't involve string manipulation
- uses Python's built-in `round`
- doesn't mutate the original timedelta, but gives a new one
- is a one liner :)

```py
import datetime

original = datetime.timedelta(seconds=50, milliseconds=20)
rounded = datetime.timedelta(seconds=round(original.total_seconds()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution that properly rounds up and down and doesn't use any string hacks:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def round_to_secs(dt: datetime) -> datetime:
    extra_sec = round(dt.microsecond / 10 ** 6)
    return dt.replace(microsecond=0) + timedelta(seconds=extra_sec)
```

Some examples:

```
now = datetime.now()
print(now)                 # 2021-07-26 10:43:54.397538
print(round_to_secs(now))  # 2021-07-26 10:43:54 -- rounded down

now = datetime.now()
print(now)                 # 2021-07-26 10:44:59.787438
print(round_to_secs(now))  # 2021-07-26 10:45:00  -- rounded up taking into account secs and minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution that only requires the standard datetime module.

```
import datetime

            currentimemili = datetime.datetime.now()
            currenttimesecs = currentimemili - \
                datetime.timedelta(microseconds=currentimemili.microsecond)
            print(currenttimesecs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed it, so I adjusted @srisaila to work for 60 sec/mins. Horribly complicated style, but basic functions.

```
def round_seconds(dts):
    result = []
    for item in dts:
        date = item.split()[0]
        h, m, s = [item.split()[1].split(':')[0],
                   item.split()[1].split(':')[1],
                   str(round(float(item.split()[1].split(':')[-1])))]
        if len(s) == 1:
            s = '0'+s
        if int(s) == 60:
            m_tmp = int(m)
            m_tmp += 1
            m = str(m_tmp)
            if(len(m)) == 1:
                m = '0'+ m
            s = '00'
        if m == 60:
            h_tmp = int(h)
            h_tmp += 1
            h = str(h_tmp)
            if(len(h)) == 1:
                print(h)
                h = '0'+ h
            m = '00'
        result.append(date + ' ' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s)
    return result
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def round_sec(dt):
   return dt.replace(microsecond=0)
```