# Pandas - Rounding off timestamps to the nearest second

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime

I am struggling to round off timestamps using pandas.

The timestamps look like this:

```
datetime.datetime(2017,06,25,00,31,53,993000)
datetime.datetime(2017,06,25,00,32,31,224000)
datetime.datetime(2017,06,25,00,33,11,223000)
datetime.datetime(2017,06,25,00,33,53,876000)
datetime.datetime(2017,06,25,00,34,31,219000)
datetime.datetime(2017,06,25,00,35,12,634000)
```

How do I round off to the nearest second?

Previously iv tried suggestions in this post but they didn't work:
[Rounding time off to the nearest second - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792242/rounding-time-off-to-the-nearest-second-python)

My code looks like this so far:

```
import pandas as pd
filename = 'data.csv'
readcsv = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

**Import data according to file header info**

```
log_date = readcsv.date
log_time = readcsv.time
log_lon = readcsv.lon
log_lat = readcsv.lat
log_heading = readcsv.heading

readcsv['date'] = pd.to_datetime(readcsv['date']).dt.date
readcsv['time'] = pd.to_datetime(readcsv['time']).dt.time
```

**Combine date and time into one variable**

```
timestamp = [datetime.datetime.combine(log_date[i],log_time[i]) for i in range(len(log_date))]
```

**Create dataframe**

```
data = {'timestamp':timestamp,'log_lon':log_lon,'log_lat':log_lat,'log_heading':log_heading}
log_data = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['timestamp','log_lon','log_lat','log_heading'])
log_data.index = log_data['timestamp']
```

I am still quite new to python so please excuse my ignorance

Comment: if accuracy isn't too important, you can just set the milliseconds to 000

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use first [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameter `parse_dates` for create `datetime`s from column `date` and `time` and then [`dt.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) for round `datetime`s:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""date,time,lon,lat,heading
2017-06-25,00:31:53.993000,48.1254,17.1458,a
2017-06-25,00:32:31.224000,48.1254,17.1458,a
2017-06-25,00:33:11.223000,48.1254,17.1458,a
2017-06-25,00:33:53.876000,48.1254,17.1458,a
2017-06-25,00:34:31.219000,48.1254,17.1458,a
2017-06-25,00:35:12.634000,48.1254,17.1458,a"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), parse_dates={'timestamp':['date','time']})

print (df)
                timestamp      lon      lat heading
0 2017-06-25 00:31:53.993  48.1254  17.1458       a
1 2017-06-25 00:32:31.224  48.1254  17.1458       a
2 2017-06-25 00:33:11.223  48.1254  17.1458       a
3 2017-06-25 00:33:53.876  48.1254  17.1458       a
4 2017-06-25 00:34:31.219  48.1254  17.1458       a
5 2017-06-25 00:35:12.634  48.1254  17.1458       a

print (df.dtypes)
timestamp    datetime64[ns]
lon                 float64
lat                 float64
heading              object
dtype: object
```

---

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.round('1s')

print (df)
            timestamp      lon      lat heading
0 2017-06-25 00:31:54  48.1254  17.1458       a
1 2017-06-25 00:32:31  48.1254  17.1458       a
2 2017-06-25 00:33:11  48.1254  17.1458       a
3 2017-06-25 00:33:54  48.1254  17.1458       a
4 2017-06-25 00:34:31  48.1254  17.1458       a
5 2017-06-25 00:35:13  48.1254  17.1458       a
```

EDIT:

If you want set column with datetimes to `index` also:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""date,time,lon,lat,heading
2017-06-25,00:31:53.993000,48.1254,17.1458,a
2017-06-25,00:32:31.224000,48.1254,17.1458,a
2017-06-25,00:33:11.223000,48.1254,17.1458,a
2017-06-25,00:33:53.876000,48.1254,17.1458,a
2017-06-25,00:34:31.219000,48.1254,17.1458,a
2017-06-25,00:35:12.634000,48.1254,17.1458,a"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), parse_dates={'timestamp':['date','time']}, index_col=['timestamp'])
print (df)
                             lon      lat heading
timestamp                                        
2017-06-25 00:31:53.993  48.1254  17.1458       a
2017-06-25 00:32:31.224  48.1254  17.1458       a
2017-06-25 00:33:11.223  48.1254  17.1458       a
2017-06-25 00:33:53.876  48.1254  17.1458       a
2017-06-25 00:34:31.219  48.1254  17.1458       a
2017-06-25 00:35:12.634  48.1254  17.1458       a
```

---

```
print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2017-06-25 00:31:53.993000', '2017-06-25 00:32:31.224000',
               '2017-06-25 00:33:11.223000', '2017-06-25 00:33:53.876000',
               '2017-06-25 00:34:31.219000', '2017-06-25 00:35:12.634000'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='timestamp', freq=None)


df.index = df.index.round('1s')
print (df)
                         lon      lat heading
timestamp                                    
2017-06-25 00:31:54  48.1254  17.1458       a
2017-06-25 00:32:31  48.1254  17.1458       a
2017-06-25 00:33:11  48.1254  17.1458       a
2017-06-25 00:33:54  48.1254  17.1458       a
2017-06-25 00:34:31  48.1254  17.1458       a
2017-06-25 00:35:13  48.1254  17.1458       a
```

Comment: i'm getting an "AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'round'"

Comment: 2 questions - what is `print (df.dtypes)` ? and what is your pandas version `print (pd.show_versions())` ?

Comment: `df.types` is exactly the same as what you had and Iv got pandas: 0.17.1

Comment: Hmmm, it is a bit old, is possible upgrade?

Comment: Because this function is implemented in `pandas 0.18` version (check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#datetimelike-rounding)) and last version of pandas is `0.21.1`

Comment: I see, thats probably been the issue all along, i'll try upgrade now. Thanks very much!

Comment: Well that's embarrassing but its finally Sorted thanks very much!!

Answer (score 4):

dt.round is what you are looking for. I'll just create a smaller version of your DataFrame, please comment if you can't modify it to fully fit your case, I can help with that also.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

ts1 = datetime.datetime(2017,06,25,00,31,53,993000)
ts2 = datetime.datetime(2017,06,25,00,32,31,224000)
ts3 = datetime.datetime(2017,06,25,00,33,11,223000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':[ts1, ts2, ts3]})

df.timestamp.dt.round('1s')
```

Gives you the following:

```
Out[89]: 
0   2017-06-25 00:31:54
1   2017-06-25 00:32:31
2   2017-06-25 00:33:11
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I had to upgrade my packages to see the functions.