# How to apply modulo operation on python datetime.time

Tags: python, datetime

I have a series of datetime.time data, and I want to apply modulo operation on it, converting all data into some intervals.

For example, using a 5-minute interval, `datetime.time(11, 38, 27, 785327)` will be converted to `datetime.time(11, 35, 0, 0)`

How can I accomplish this sort of rounding?

Comment: check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463930/how-to-round-the-minute-of-a-datetime-object-python/10854034#10854034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input_time = datetime.time(11, 38, 27, 785327)
mod_time = datetime.time(input_time.hour, input_time.minute//5*5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Came across this execellent solution

https://gist.github.com/treyhunner/6218526

```
import datetime as dt


class datetime(dt.datetime):
    def __divmod__(self, delta):
        seconds = int((self - dt.datetime.min).total_seconds())
        remainder = dt.timedelta(
            seconds=seconds % delta.total_seconds(),
            microseconds=self.microsecond,
        )
        quotient = self - remainder
        return quotient, remainder

    def __floordiv__(self, delta):
        return divmod(self, delta)[0]

    def __mod__(self, delta):
        return divmod(self, delta)[1]
```