# Round time to nearest hour python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I was trying to round off time to the nearest hour in python in a dataframe.

Suppose if a timestamp is `2017-11-18 0:16` it should come as `2017-11-18 0:00`
and `2017-11-18 1:56` should round off as `2017-11-18 2:00`

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Show us some code, why are you not getting it?

Comment: Please (re-)read "[ask]", then [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates what you've tried and what didn't work.

Comment: @user123, did one of the below solutions help? if so, feel free to accept one (tick on left).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I experimented a bit with jpp but ended up with a different solution as adding one hour at hour 23 crashed the thing.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()

def hour_rounder(t):
    # Rounds to nearest hour by adding a timedelta hour if minute >= 30
    return (t.replace(second=0, microsecond=0, minute=0, hour=t.hour)
               +timedelta(hours=t.minute//30))

print(now)
print(hour_rounder(now))
```

Returns:

```
2018-02-22 23:42:43.352133
2018-02-23 00:00:00
```

Comment: hour=t.hour necessary?

Comment: @kmecpp hi there. Yes, as this function rounds the hour we need t.hour to retrieve the hour from our datetime.

Comment: But we're doing t.replace() on the original datetime. Wont it already have that hour?

Comment: @kmecpp True! But this follow the Python Zen. Explicit is better than implicit. So if we would exclude that someone might ask the opposite.

Answer (score 18):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Timestamp.now().round('60min').to_pydatetime()
```

Returns:

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 23, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 12):

This is one way.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

def rounder(t):
    if t.minute >= 30:
        return t.replace(second=0, microsecond=0, minute=0, hour=t.hour+1)
    else:
        return t.replace(second=0, microsecond=0, minute=0)

now           # 2018-02-22 22:03:53.831589
rounder(now)  # 2018-02-22 22:00:00.000000
```

Comment: Sorry for experimenting with your solution. I rolled it back. Basically I found that it would crash when hour 23 turned hour 24. I could have changed your solution but ended up posting my own. I gave you an upvote though.

Answer (score 5):

There is a general function to round a datetime at any time lapse in seconds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10854034/1431079)

Sample:

```
print roundTime(datetime.datetime(2012,12,31,23,44,59,1234),roundTo=60*60)
--> 2013-01-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who need to change a whole column:

```
df = df['Timestamp'].dt.round('60min')
```

You can also use ceil() and floor() functions to replace round, depending on the rules you want to approximate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it (based on another solution provided here)

```
def round_to_closest_hour(dttm):
    add_hour = True if dttm.minute >= 30 else False
    dttm = dttm.replace(second=0, microsecond=0, minute=0)
    if add_hour:
        dttm += timedelta(hours=1)
    return dttm
```

Basically, check if an hour is needed to be added or not (depending on whether it's past 30 minutes mark). Then reset `minutes, seconds, microseconds` and add an `hour` if required.