# Create a new column from a datetime column in a pandas dataframe by rounding to the nearest hour

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, rounding

Add a column (called TIME_HOURS) based on the data in the TIME column and rounded up
the value to the nearest hour.  For example, if the original TIME row said:
‘02/28/2018 05:40:00 PM’ we want ‘2018-02-28 18:00:00’
(the change is that 5:40pm was rounded up to 6:00pm and the TIME_HOUR column is
actually a proper datetime and not a string).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round time to nearest hour python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937900/round-time-to-nearest-hour-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.Series.dt.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html):

```
df["TIME_HOURS"].dt.round('H')
```