How can I fix it so that this function does not fill up the RAM?
Every time I call the function, xlsx is exported from Mysql. But why is the data written to RAM (+ 1GB) and not released until you delete the object and run the garbage collector? You can somehow decide that the data from the database is not written to RAM, but written to a temporary file. Or maybe my request code is wrong, then can you help me with this.
@sync_to_async
@login_required
def export_excel(request):
    chars = 'abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    number = int(10)
    length = int(10)
    for n in range(number):
        password = ''
        for i in range(length):
            password += random.choice(chars)
    pricesecret = Price.objects.get(id=1)
    path = "/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + ""
    path2 = "/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/zip"
    path3 = "/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/rar"
    path4 = "/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/xlsx"
    try:
        os.makedirs(path)
        os.makedirs(path2)
        os.makedirs(path3)
        os.makedirs(path4)
    except:
        path = "/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + ""
        path2 = "/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/zip"
        path3 = "/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/rar"
        path4 = "/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/xlsx"
    xlsxpathname = os.listdir("/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/xlsx")
    zippathname = os.listdir("/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/zip")
    if xlsxpathname:
            xlsxpathname = ''.join(map(str, xlsxpathname))
            filepath = '/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/' + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + '/xlsx/' + xlsxpathname
    if zippathname:
            zippathname = ''.join(map(str, zippathname))
            filepath4 = '/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/' + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + '/zip/' + zippathname
    filepath2 = '/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/' + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + '/rar/' + pricesecret.url + '.lock'
    if os.path.exists(filepath2) and os.path.exists(filepath) and os.stat(filepath).st_size != 0 and os.stat(filepath4).st_size != 0:
        url = "https://localhost/media/pricenew/" + str(
            request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/zip/" + zippathname
        return JsonResponse({'pricesecret': zippathname, 'url': url,})
    else:
        files = os.listdir("/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/rar/")
        files2 = os.listdir("/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/xlsx/")
        files3 = os.listdir("/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/zip/")
        if files:
            onlyfiles3 = os.listdir("/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/rar/")
            onlyfiles3 = ''.join(map(str, onlyfiles3))
            eawa3 = "/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/rar/"
            os.remove(eawa3 + onlyfiles3)
        if files2:
            onlyfiles1 = os.listdir("/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/xlsx/")
            onlyfiles1 = ''.join(map(str, onlyfiles1))
            eawa = "/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/xlsx/"
            os.remove(eawa + onlyfiles1)
        if files3:
            onlyfiles2 = os.listdir("/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/zip/")
            onlyfiles2 = ''.join(map(str, onlyfiles2))
            eawa2 = "/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/zip/"
            os.remove(eawa2 + onlyfiles2)
        file_lock = open(filepath2, "wb")
        price_title = "Прайс_" + datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        headers = (
            'Код', 'Артикул', 'Наименование', 'Производитель', 'Ед', 'Цена,руб', 'Остаток', 'Заявка',
            'Норма отпуска', 'Новинка!')
        data = []
        data = tablib.Dataset(data, headers=headers, title=price_title)
        products = Product.objects.filter(stock__gt=0, published=True).select_related('brand',
                                                                                      'product_sklad').prefetch_related(
            'brand__clt1__client_id__discount_list_k1', 'category__parent', ).exclude(
            product_sklad__gte=1)
        saleban = Salenban.objects.filter(client_id=request.user.usrid.listusers_id,
                                          published=1).select_related('client_id',
                                                                      'mf_un').prefetch_related(
            'client_id__discount_list_k1').values_list('mf_un', flat=True)
        post = []
        for person in saleban:
            post.append(person)
        if saleban.exists():
            for pos in post:
                products = products.filter.exclude(brand=pos)
        else:
            products = products
        for book in products:
            zayvka = ""
            if book.artikul == "None":
                book.artikul = ""
            if book.brand == "None":
                book.brand = ""
            if book.new_product == 0:
                book.new_product = ""
            if book.stock > 50:
                book.stock = ">50"
            data.append((book.id_p, book.artikul, book.name, book.brand, book.shtuk_e, round(book.user_max2(), 2),
                         book.stock, zayvka, book.min_kol, book.new_product))
        def zip(src, dst):
            zf = zipfile.ZipFile(dst, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel = 9)
            abs_src = os.path.abspath(src)
            for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
                for filename in files:
                    absname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
                    arcname = absname[len(abs_src) + 1:]
                    print('zipping %s as %s' % (os.path.join(dirname, filename),arcname))
                    zf.write(absname, arcname)
            zf.close()
        with open("/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/xlsx/price_" + password + ".xlsx",
                  "wb") as f_price:
            f_price.write(data.export('xlsx'))
            f_price.close()
            del f_price
        dst = "/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/zip/price_" + password + ".zip"
        src =  "/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/xlsx/"
        zip(src, dst)
        #os.remove("/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/" + str(request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/zip/price.xlsx")
        del data
        del post
        del headers
        del book
        del price_title
        del products
        del saleban
        gc.collect()
        url = "https://localhost/media/pricenew/" + str(
            request.user.usrid.listusers_id) + "/zip/price_" + password + ".zip"
        return JsonResponse({'pricesecret': password + ".zip", 'url': url})



There's quite a lot going on in your code with little clarity where the problem is. 1. You are potentially querying quite a lot of data (I say potentially because you don't mention how much data the queries return) 2. You are collecting this data into a tablib.Dataset object (I am not an SME on this). 3. You are then writing this out into a zip file. It might be better if you narrowed this problem down and asked about the first specific point you feel where the data is getting too much for your server.

Excel file are zipped XML files. You cannot chunk it for IO operation as you can with a CSV.

I could recommend you to use the iterator method of the QuerySet but I am not quite sure whether that would help since you are collecting the data anyways in another object.

your file is not what is causing the RAM overload, it is the amount of data in data. instead of storing all data in data and then putting it into excel. you should keep adding the rows in Excel(preferably CSV(if really need excel, manually convert it)) as soon as you have data.

Can you please give an example in this case of how to do it?

Thanks, I'm trying the iterator. and now the error is that the 'generator' object does not have the 'exists' attribute on the line with the if saleban.exists() condition:
How can I spell this out better?

why not shift load to message broker?

Write to CSV and/or JSON rows.

Every time you call this, it tries to zip all prior results right? Or do you want to zip only only the most recent result?

Though it si a bit hard to tell, I think you might look at stream reading and writing your data. This should/might produce a CSV that is valid for an hour for the given client. I have not tested this so it might be full of errors.
This also just produces the raw CSV file not the zip file and if you need the final result to be a zip file then you can create it with a .tmp name and rename it once done instead.
The key here is that hopefully we never need to load our complete products data into memory at once.
import os
import pathlib
import datetime
import datetime
import hashlib
import csv

from django.http import JsonResponse

##-----------------------------
## Round time to nearest hour
## https://stackoverflow.com/a/48938464/218663
##-----------------------------
def hour_rounder(t):
    return (
        t.replace(second=0, microsecond=0, minute=0, hour=t.hour)
        + datetime.timedelta(hours=t.minute//30)
    )
##-----------------------------

@sync_to_async
@login_required
def export_data(request):
    client_id = request.user.usrid.listusers_id
    root_folder = "/var/www/django/mysite/static/media/pricenew/"
    target_folder = f"{root_folder}{client_id}"
    current_hour = hour_rounder(datetime.datetime.now())
    current_slug = hashlib.sha256(str(current_hour).encode()).hexdigest()
    target_file_name  = f"prince_{current_slug}.csv"
    target_file_path = f"{target_folder}/{target_file_name}"
    root_url = "https://localhost/media/pricenew/"
    target_url = f"{root_url}{client_id}/{target_file_name}"

    ##------------------------
    ## if a recent export exists return the data for it
    ##------------------------
    if os.path.exists(target_file_path):
        return JsonResponse({"pricesecret": target_file_name, "url": target_url})
    ##------------------------

    ##------------------------
    ## make sure we have a target folder to write to
    ##------------------------
    pathlib.Path(target_folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    ##------------------------

    ##------------------------
    ## get the names we want to exclude as a set
    ##------------------------
    saleban = set(Salenban
        .objects
        .filter(client_id=client_id, published=1)
        .select_related("client_id", "mf_un")
        .prefetch_related("client_id__discount_list_k1")
        .values_list("mf_un", flat=True).iterator()
    )
    ##------------------------

    ##------------------------
    ##  interesting products
    ##------------------------
    products = (Product
        .objects
        .filter(stock__gt=0, published=True)
        .select_related("brand","product_sklad")
        .prefetch_related("brand__clt1__client_id__discount_list_k1", "category__parent")
        .exclude(product_sklad__gte=1).iterator()
    )
    ##------------------------

    ##------------------------
    ## a list of CSV headers
    ##------------------------
    headers = [
        "Код",
        "Артикул",
        "Наименование",
        "Производитель",
        "Ед",
        "Цена,руб",
        "Остаток",
        "Заявка",
        "Норма отпуска",
        "Новинка!"
    ]
    ##------------------------

    ##------------------------
    ## stream write to a temporary CSV path
    ##------------------------
    with open(target_file_path + ".tmp",  "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as f_price:
        writer = csv.writer(f_price)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        for book in products:
            if book.brand in saleban:
                continue

            writer.writerow([
                book.id_p,
                "" if book.artikul == "None" else book.artikul,
                book.name,
                "" if book.brand == "None" else book.brand,
                book.shtuk_e,
                book.price,
                ">50" if book.stock > 50 else book.stock,
                "",
                book.min_kol,
                "" if book.new_product == 0 else book.new_product
            ])
    ##------------------------

    ##------------------------
    ## Now that the file is complete, rename it to expose it.
    ##------------------------
    os.rename(target_file_path + ".tmp", target_file_path)
    ##------------------------

    return JsonResponse({"pricesecret": target_file_name, "url": target_url})


The leak is still there! This code with removing data does not help! In my "cron", the daphne (asgi) service was restarted every 5 minutes, so the memory was cleared. But I would like to free up my memory without crutches.

Add iterator ....
Price for a long time 3-5 minutes. Before this, it took 30-40 seconds to form.

replaced check temporarily
round(book.user_max2(), 2),
added
book.price
The price was generated instantly and did not take up RAM in memory.
This means that the problem is also in the product method user_max2()

I will be grateful if anyone can help with user_max2()

Sure thing though I will not be able to get to it for a few hours. You might need a new question if you need a faster answer about user_max2()

Yes, I thought I’d better publish it in a new question! This is a difficult question for me.thank you

@jonSG Continued here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78365668/how-to-correctly-derive-a-function-book-user-max2-to-make-xlsx-export-fast  If you can tell me something about this
