how to correctly derive a function book.user_max2() to make xlsx export fast
When exporting .xlsx, the book.user_max2() function increases the load and clogs up the RAM. If you just take book.price from the model, there is no such problem. But I need the price to change when unloaded, so I wrote a user_max2() function in the Products model.
Everything is a problem
in the user_max2() function.
Without it, everything is unloaded quickly and there are no memory leaks. Please help, maybe someone has already encountered this.
model Products
class Product(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Not published'),
        (1, 'published'),
    )
    STATUS_NEW = (
        (0, 'No'),
        (1, 'Yes'),
    )
    id_p = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_index=True, unique=True, verbose_name='ID продукта')
    artikul = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, blank=True, verbose_name='artikul ')
    brend = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, blank=True, verbose_name='brend')
    analog = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True, related_name='categ', verbose_name='category')
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='brand')
    product_sklad = models.ForeignKey(Sklad, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1, verbose_name='product_sklad ID')
    product_time = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='time')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, verbose_name='name')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='description ')
    price = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Price")
    zakup = models.FloatField(default=price, blank=True, verbose_name="")
    discount_product_min = models.FloatField(default=0,
                                             verbose_name='Minimum discount factor')
    price_magazin = models.FloatField(default=0, blank=True, verbose_name="Minimum retail price")
    upakovka_f = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, verbose_name='',
                                  help_text="")
    shtuk_e = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50, verbose_name='',
                               help_text=" ")
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='')
    stock_k13 = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Quantity of goods in transit', blank=True)
    min_kol = models.IntegerField(default=1, db_index=True, verbose_name='')
    new_product = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=STATUS_NEW, verbose_name='New')
    da_product = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=0, blank=True, verbose_name='')
    published = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=True, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name='')
    updated = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False, blank=True, verbose_name='')

    def user_max2(self):
        user = get_current_user()
        user_k = user.usrid.discount_list_k1.group_discount_list_k
        listusers_id = user.usrid.listusers_id
        brand2 = self.brand.clt1.all()

        for pr in brand2:
            if pr.published == 1:
                if pr.mf_id == self.brand.brand_id and pr.client_id.listusers_id == listusers_id:
                    if pr.k_dn == 1:
                        return self.zakup * pr.k_up
                    else:
                        user_max = max(pr.k_dn, self.discount_product_min)
                        return self.price * user_max
        user_max = max(user_k, self.discount_product_min)

other models
class Clients(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (0, ''),
        (1, ''),
    )
    client_id = models.ForeignKey(ListUsers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='ID clients')
    mf_id = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='ID brand')
    k_up = models.FloatField(default=1, verbose_name='Markup to purchase price')
    k_dn = models.FloatField(default=1, verbose_name='Sale price discount')
    published = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=True, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name='')
    updated = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False, blank=True, verbose_name='')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('client_id',)
        verbose_name = ''
        verbose_name_plural = 'Individual discounts for the manufacturer'
        unique_together = ('client_id', 'mf_id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.client_id}'


class Brand(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (0, ''),
        (1, ''),
    )
    brand_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_index=True, unique=True, verbose_name='ID')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='name')
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, blank=True, verbose_name='URL')
    clt1 = models.ManyToManyField(Clients, through="Brand2")
    published = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=True, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name='')
    updated = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False, blank=True, verbose_name='')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'Brand'
        verbose_name_plural = ''

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('brand', kwargs={'brand_id': self.pk})


class Brand2(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (0, ''),
        (1, ''),
    )
    brand_id = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='ID brand')
    clients_id = models.ForeignKey(Clients, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='ID clients')
    published = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=True, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name='')
    updated = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False, blank=True, verbose_name='')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('clients_id',)
        verbose_name = 'Individual discounts for the manufacturer2'
        verbose_name_plural = ''
        unique_together = ('brand_id', 'clients_id')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.clients_id}'

views
def export_excel(request):
    products = (Product
                .objects
                .filter(stock__gt=0, published=True)
                .select_related("brand", "product_sklad")
                .prefetch_related("brand__clt1__client_id__discount_list_k1", "category__parent")
                .exclude(product_sklad__gte=1)
                )
    headers = (
        'Code', 'Article', 'Name', 'Manufacturer', 'Unit', 'Price', 'Remaining', 'Application',
        'Normal vacation', 'New!')
    data = tablib.Dataset( headers=headers, title="1212")
    for book in products.iterator():
        zayvka = ""
        if book.artikul == "None":
            book.artikul = ""
        if book.brand == "None":
            book.brand = ""
        if book.new_product == 0:
            book.new_product = ""
        if book.stock > 50:
            book.stock = ">50"
        data.append((book.id_p, book.artikul, book.name, book.brand, book.shtuk_e, book.user_max2(),
                     book.stock, zayvka, book.min_kol, book.new_product))
    with open("price_.xlsx", "wb") as f_price:
        f_price.write(data.export('xlsx'))
        f_price.close()
    return HttpResponse('ok')


Hint: You need to use a generator or iterator
