# Python reads inaccurately from Excel Date/Time field

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to read an Excel file with [OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io), but the values from Date/Time fields are not accurate.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('doc.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

for rowNum in range(2, ws.max_row + 1):
    date = ws['A' + str(rowNum)].value
    print(date)
```

Excel data: 2019-08-16 06:55:00

Value I get in Python: 2019-08-16 06:54:59.999996

How could I read Date/Time fields accurately?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate ?

Answer (score 1):

## The problem

[According to this issue](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/919/datetime-cell-value-is-saved-with), the problem is a result of Excel's implementation; not OpenPyXL's:

> The XLSX file format cannot be relied upon to store dates and times accurately. These are always converted internally to a serial form of limited precision.

## Work-around option 1: Text

You could represent the values as text in Excel and [then parse that text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/7232335). For example...

Say you have a Date value in cell A2 with the custom format "m/d/yy h:mm:ss":

8/16/19 6:55:00

In a separate column, you can write the formula

`=TEXT(A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"T"&TEXT(A2,"hh:mm:ss")`

and copy to other cells in the column, resulting in

2019-08-16T06:55:00

If you don't want this separate column, just overwrite column A by copying and pasting the **values** from the new text column into it.

Now, when you read the values you'll need to be careful to use the option `data_only=True` with `openpyxl.load_workbook` so you read the actual value of the text; not the formula.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('doc.xlsx', data_only=True)
ws = wb.active

for rowNum in range(2, ws.max_row + 1):
    date = ws['A' + str(rowNum)].value
    print(date)
```

Then parse the text in `date` [according to the ISO 8601 format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/7232335).

## Work-around option 2: Rounding

One drawback to the text option is that it requires more work in the Excel spreadsheet. If you know the precision you're going for, you can have Python round the values for you.

**Caution** should be taken, however! If the desired precision is too small, the lack of precision on Excel's part could conceivably result in rounding to incorrect numbers. This could be especially true of compounding formulas, such as `=<above cell>+1/24`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3463930/7232335) (and particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3464000/7232335)) for a good solution to rounding datetimes. Here's a spin-off of solution I used for my own code (note f-string use; you'll need to use `str.format()` if you're using Python < 3.6):

```
import datetime as dt

def round_datetime(d, precision='second'):
    """Round a datetime to the named precision.

    Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3464000/7232335
    """
    d += dt.timedelta(**{f"{precision}s": 1}) / 2
    d -= dt.timedelta(minutes=d.minute,
        seconds=d.second,
        microseconds=d.microsecond)
    return d  # Return optional, since object d is modified in-place.
```

---

## Side note:

There are Worksheet methods available for iterating through rows with OpenPyXL:

### 1. `ws.iter_rows()`

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
    date = row[0]
```

### 2. `ws.values`

Same as `ws.iter_rows()` with no arguments except `values_only=True`.

```
values = ws.values
next(values)  # Discard first row.
for row in values:
    date = row[0]
```

### 3. `ws.rows`

Same as `ws.iter_rows()` with no arguments.

```
rows = ws.rows
next(rows)  # Discard first row.
for row in ws.rows:
    date = row[0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are referring to the correct Excel file and the value is written as it is? Tried to replicate:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('doc.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

date = ws['A1'].value
print(date)
```

and this is what I got with Python3 and Excel 2010:

[image]

Comment: Verify the oposite, write with python `2019-08-16 06:54:59.999996`. I guess Execl shows `2019-08-16 06:55:00`.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I am referring to the right file. I tried oposite - whether I write with Python or just paste to Excel `2019-08-16 06:54:59.999996` it shows `2019-08-16 06:55:00` anyway. Not sure how to deal this inaccuracy, the result can be very wrong when working with a lot of data.

Comment: @Vaidas - try creating a new Excel file and write exactly "2019-08-16 06:55:00" in A1. Then run my code. What do you get?

Comment: I tried creating new Excel file and writing exactly "2019-08-16 06:55:00", but the result is the same 2019-08-16 06:54:59.999996.