# How to round datetime previous 10 minute with python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to get the last 10 minutes in python to be fully divisible by 10.

It shouldn't round to the next 10 minutes, it must be always previous 10 minutes.

For example, output should be as follows:

> 2019-10-04 20:45:34.903000  -> 2019-10-04 20:40
>
> 2019-10-04 20:48:35.403000  -> 2019-10-04 20:40
>
> 2019-10-04 20:42:21.903000  -> 2019-10-04 20:40
>
> 2019-10-04 20:50:21.204000  -> 2019-10-04 20:50
>
> 2019-10-04 20:59:49.602100  -> 2019-10-04 20:50

```
import datetime

def timeround10(dt):
    #...


print timeround10(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: So do you want to modify the datetime object or get a string? Also, have you tried? What do your attempts look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round the minute of a datetime object python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463930/how-to-round-the-minute-of-a-datetime-object-python)

Comment: It is not duplicate. The example in the link you gave rounds to the nearest. For example: 10:46  to  10:50

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to construct a new `datetime` with the desired values.

```
def timeround10(dt):
    return datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, (dt.minute // 10) * 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def timeround10(dt):
    return dt.replace(second=dt.second // 10, microsecond=0)
```