# Convert string timedelta to rounded timedelta to the full hour and minutes

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to round the time_delta that is declared as a string to the full hour and minute

```
    date        stores              count   time_delta
0   2020-06-30  purchaseDateStoreA  334     02:07:26.681396
1   2020-06-30  purchaseDateStoreB  423     01:07:26.681396
2   2020-07-01  purchaseDateStoreA  294     03:46:27.282249
```

Desired Output

```
    date        stores              count   time_delta
0   2020-06-30  purchaseDateStoreA  334     02:07
1   2020-06-30  purchaseDateStoreB  423     01:07
2   2020-07-01  purchaseDateStoreA  294     03:46
```

This is how I computed time_delta:

```
df['purchaseDateStoreA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp_storeA'])
df['purchaseDateStoreB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp_storeB'])

df['time_delta'] = df['purchaseDateStoreB'] - df['purchaseDateStoreA']
```

Comment: possibly a duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463930/how-to-round-the-minute-of-a-datetime-object

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
df['time_delta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time_delta']).dt.floor('Min')
```

Output:

```
         date              stores  count time_delta
0  2020-06-30  purchaseDateStoreA    334   02:07:00
1  2020-06-30  purchaseDateStoreB    423   01:07:00
2  2020-07-01  purchaseDateStoreA    294   03:46:00
```