# Is there any good idea to ceil or floor datetime in python3?

Tags: python, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
roughtime = datetime(2018,1,1,5,2,1)
```

I want to floor `roughtime` as `datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)` and also ceil `roughtime` as `datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0)`.

Is there any convenient way to realize this? I know I can convert `roughtime` using matplotlib.dates.date2num. But I wonder if there are other ingenious ideas

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3463930/10197418

Comment: if you happen to work with `pandas`, you'd have `round`, `floor` and `ceil` methods which you could use to round to a certain frequency, e.g. `pd.Timestamp('2018-1-1 05:02:01').ceil('D')` -> `Timestamp('2018-01-02 00:00:00')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace` function to replace the time part to make it `floor` and add one day to make it `ceil`

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: def ceil(datetimeObj):
   ...:     return floor(datetimeObj) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
   ...:

In [3]: def floor(datetimeObj):
   ...:     return datetimeObj.replace(second=0, hour=0, minute=0)
   ...:

In [4]: roughtime = datetime.datetime(2018,1,1,5,2,1)

In [5]: ceil(roughtime)
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2, 0, 0)

In [6]: floor(roughtime)
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: What about the case where datetime obj is ceiled already. It will bump 1 day. The other answer addresses this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`datetime.combine(date, time)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) to create new datetime object using given `datetime.date` and `datetime.time`.

#### Floor

```
from datetime import datetime
floored = datetime.combine(roughtime.date(), datetime.min.time())
```

#### Ceil

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

if roughtime.time() == datetime.min.time():
    ceiled = roughtime
else:
    ceiled = datetime.combine(roughtime.date()+timedelta(days=1), datetime.min.time())
```

- Ceiling needs `if..else` statement since if you would ceil `2020-07-24 00:00:00` one would not expect to get `2020-07-25 00:00:00`
- `ceiled =  roughtime` is okay (no need to make a copy), since `datetime` objects are *immutable*. ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types))

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a pandas datetime object like this:

```
pd.to_datetime(now).floor('H')
```

where now can be a datetime object or a string