# How to asign Datetime values of a dataframe to the next 15min Timestep without using min/max/sum or mean?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I've got a dataframe with power profiles. The dataframe shows start and endtime and consumed power during a transaction. It looks something like this:

| TransactionId | StartTime | EndTime | Power |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyza123 | 2018.01.01 07:07:34 | 2018.01.01 07:34:08 | 70 |
| hjker383 | 2018.01.01 10:21:00 | 2018.01.01 11:40:08 | 23 |

My Goal is to assign a new Start- and EndTime which are set at 15 min values. Like so:

| TransactionId | StartTime | New Starttime | EndTime | New EndTime | Power |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyza123 | 2018.01.01 07:07:34 | 2018.01.01 07:00:00 | 2018.01.01 07:34:08 | 2018.01.01 07:30:00 | 70 |
| hjker383 | 2018.01.01 10:21:00 | 2018.01.01 10:30:00 | 2018.01.01 11:40:08 | 2018.01.01 11:45:00 | 23 |

The old Timestamps can be deleted afterwards. However I don't want to aggregate them. So I guess

> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="StartTime", freq="15min")).sum()

or

> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="StartEndtime", freq="15min")).mean()

etc. is not an option.
Another idea I had was creating a dataframe with values between `2018.01.01 00:00:00` and `2018.01.01 23:45:00`. However I am not sure how to iterate true the two dataframes, to achieve my goal and if iteration true dataframes is a good idea in the first place.

Comment: In your code -- 7:07:34 is being converted to 7:00:00 (going down) but 11:40:08 is being converted to 11:45:00 (going up), even though both are greater than midpoint. Is there a logic or is this a mistake?

Comment: It's a small mistake, since I ignored the secounds. However they should be ignored in the later code as well. So I might need to convert to `%H:%M`  first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to convert a datetime to nearest 15 minute and then apply it to the column
This function was inspired from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463930/how-to-round-the-minute-of-a-datetime-object):

```
import datetime

def convertToNearest15(tm):
    discard = datetime.timedelta(minutes=tm.minute % 15,
                             seconds=tm.second,
                             microseconds=tm.microsecond)
    tm -= discard
    if discard >= datetime.timedelta(minutes=7.5):
        tm += datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
    return tm


df['startTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startTime'])
df['newStartTime'] = df['startTime'].apply(convertToNearest15)
df['endTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['endTime'])
df['newEndTime'] = df['endTime'].apply(convertToNearest15)
```

Here's the result:

```
id     | startTime              | endTime               |  newStartTime     | newEndTime
xyza123 | 2018-01-01 07:07:34   | 2018-01-01 10:21:00   | 2018-01-01 07:15:00   | 2018-01-01 10:15:00
hjker383| 2018-01-01 07:34:08   |2018-01-01 11:40:08    |2018-01-01 07:30:00    |2018-01-01 11:45:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Resampling the Start and Endtime to 15 mins freq

```
df['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.StartTime)
df['EndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.EndTime)
df = df.resample('15min', on='StartTime').first().dropna().rename_axis('New Starttime').reset_index()
df = df.resample('15min', on='EndTime').first().dropna().rename_axis('New EndTime').reset_index()
```

**Output**

Please rearrange the df columns as per requirement

```
    New EndTime         New Starttime   TransactionId   StartTime   EndTime Power
0   2018-01-01 07:30:00 2018-01-01 07:00:00 xyza123 2018-01-01 07:07:34 2018-01-01 07:34:08 70.0
1   2018-01-01 11:30:00 2018-01-01 10:15:00 hjker383    2018-01-01 10:21:00 2018-01-01 11:40:08 23.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['new_date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(minute=(x.minute//15 * 15), second=0))
```

Comment: This answer does not explain why it works, how can one learn from it?